# PDO SELECT WHERE not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pdo

I am trying to execute the following statements:

```
$statement = $database->prepare("SELECT userID FROM user_sessions WHERE sessionID = ?");
$statement->execute(array($sessionID));
```

However, they fail to return the userID ($statement->rowCount() returns 0). If I modify the statements like this, it works but becomes vulnerable to SQL Injection.

```
$statement = $database->prepare("SELECT userID FROM user_sessions WHERE sessionID = '$sessionID'");
$statement->execute();
```

sessionID is a hash generated from PHP password_hash() function and is obtained via PHP $_GET.

Why don't the first two statements work and how can I correct them?

UPDATE:
This is what I have discovered so far:

print_r($sessionID) outputs

```
$2y$10$YW2.87KPO2FqFxZD9jjH7ulmPXR2Mdy7Q2c\/RXjSJjH2yt.Q37aQS
```

var_export($sessionID) outputs

```
'$2y$10$YW2.87KPO2FqFxZD9jjH7ulmPXR2Mdy7Q2c\\/RXjSJjH2yt.Q37aQS'
```

The original $sessionID (value in database) is

```
$2y$10$YW2.87KPO2FqFxZD9jjH7ulmPXR2Mdy7Q2c/RXjSJjH2yt.Q37aQS
```

Comment: When you say "they fail to return the userID", what exactly are you getting?  For example, what does a var_export() of $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) look like?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. $statement->rowCount() returns 0. That's what I mean.

Comment: Okay, some database engines don't return anything for PDOStatement::rowCount() for select results (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) but I'll assume you have tested to see that no rows are returned.  What does var_export($sessionID); return at this point in the code?

Comment: Okay, I think I found the problem. When I var_export $sessionID, it returns me the $sessionID with backslashes added, even though I did not explicitly escape characters. It seems like PHP $_GET automatically adds it in. I have to stripslashes() to remove them before the above query worked. Thanks for your prompts, @jpheldson!

Comment: Be aware that var_export() will add character escape sequences to output valid PHP code.  The backslashes may be a red herring because they would likely have loused up your second example as well.

Comment: You are right. With stripslashes, the second example now fails. I still don't understand why my first example fails.

Comment: What does var_export($sessionID); return at this point in the code?

Comment: I edited my question to give more details about the problem. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106799/discussion-between-mohideen-imran-khan-and-jpheldson).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ro/pdostatement.rowcount.php rowcount might not return the number of rows for SELECT you need to manually add a COUNT

Comment: I've sorted out the problem. The function I was using to URL encode my sessionID automatically added a backslash before any forward slash. Hence, parameterised PDO statement failed. Somehow, the non-parameterised statement processes the backward slash (thus it escapes the meaning of the forward slash only) and the sessionID now becomes the same as the original sessionID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've sorted out the problem. The function I was using to URL encode my sessionID automatically added a backslash before any forward slash. Hence, parameterised PDO statement failed. Somehow, the non-parameterised statement processes the backward slash (thus it escapes the meaning of the forward slash only) and the sessionID now becomes the same as the original sessionID.